# Grok Conditional pattern in Logstash yaml (if..else)

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, devops, logstash-grok

I would like to do grok pattern based on filter conditions using if-else. I've tried but I got the wrong output. Please help me on identifying the error here.

```
filter {
  if ([service] =~ /service-name/) {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] "}
    }
 }
 else{
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] \[%{WORD:logLevel}\] \[\{\"id\":%{DATA:id},\"data\":%{DATA:response}\]"}
     }
   }
 }
}
```

and below is the log for which I want to do grok pattern

```
[11/Jul/2022:09:20:09 +0000]|| 00.0.0.000 || "-" || "POST /api/v1/path/subpath HTTP/1.1" || 200 || 630 || 0.005 || "okhttp/4.9.0"
```

Comment: are you sure that field named `service` exist ?

Comment: @PapeBADIANE yeah sure, I've added a custom field and I can able to see that in kibana dashboard

Comment: from which layer you added the field ? in logstash input or filter ? kibana ? or other ?

Comment: In kibana have you the tag _grokparsefailure when `service == name-service` ?

Comment: @PapeBADIANE I've added a tag in filebeat --> logstash. yes, it's showing tag _grokparsefailure when service == name-service, but it's not showing that error for else condition grok.

Comment: @PapeBADIANE I've added the log also for which I'm trying to do grok filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first grok the timestamp is HTTPDATE format instead of ISO8601 format, you must change it. Delete also the white space after `\]`

Here my suggestions

```
filter {
  if ([service] =~ /service-name/) or ([service] =~ /service-name1/) {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{HTTPDATE:time}\]\|\| %{IP:ip} \|\| "%{DATA}" \|\| "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}))" \|\| %{NUMBER:response} \|\| (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) \|\| (?:%{NUMBER:duration}|-) \|\| %{QS:user-agent}"}
    }
 }
 else{
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] \[%{WORD:logLevel}\] \[\{\"id\":%{DATA:id},\"data\":%{DATA:response}\]"}
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes you're right, and how can we add OR condition in if statement. Ex. `if ([service] =~ /service-name/ || [service] =~ /service-name1/)` . please update your answer with this also.

Comment: I update my answer and add the right grok pattern of the whole message